# Pinning an empty array

Tags: interop, c++-cli

In C++/CLI, is it possible to pin an array that contains no elements?

e.g.

```
array<System::Byte>^ bytes = gcnew array<System::Byte>(0);
pin_ptr<System::Byte> pin = &bytes[0]; //<-- IndexOutOfRangeException occurs here
```

The advice given by MSDN does not cover the case of empty arrays.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/18132394%28v=VS.100%29.aspx

As an aside, you may wonder why I would want to pin an empty array. The short answer is that I want to treat empty and non-empty arrays the same for code simplicity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nope, not with pin_ptr<>.  You could fallback to GCHandle to achieve the same:

```
using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;
...
    array<Byte>^ arr = gcnew array<Byte>(0);
    GCHandle hdl = GCHandle::Alloc(arr, GCHandleType::Pinned);
    try {
        unsigned char* ptr = (unsigned char*)(void*)hdl.AddrOfPinnedObject();
        // etc..
    }
    finally {
        hdl.Free();
    }
```

Sounds to me you should be using `List<Byte>^` instead btw.

Comment: Thanks for the working answer! Regarding your comment about using `List<Byte>^`, is there some benefit other than being dynamically resizable? Resizing is not an issue for me in the particular scenario.

Comment: Just that you sounded like you were resizing arrays.  Ignore.

Comment: On second thought, why don't you just pass a null pointer?  You should never dereference the pointer you get anyway.  At least with a null pointer you'll notice.

Comment: Ah, because this array of N length is a return value from a method. The caller uses the result, and an array of zero length should be a valid return value. You make a good point, but in this special case it doesn't apply.

Comment: This sounds very wrong.  Do *not* use the pointer you get from pin_ptr<> or GCHandle beyond their scope.  You'll corrupt the garbage collected heap when the collector moves the array.  You cannot return the pointer as a function return value.

Comment: This method pins the array before passing it to a native method. It then unpins the array and returns the managed reference to the managed caller. Sorry I left that detail out.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot pin a cli object `array` with 0 zero elements because the array has no memory backing.  You obviously cannot pin something that has no memory to point to.

The cli object `array` metadata still exists, however, and it states that the array length is 0.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, Hans has proven that you can pin an empty array. What is obvious to me is not always correct. Looks like I'm not the only one. :D