# IntPtr vs C++ pointers

Tags: pointers, c++-cli

I presume answers are going to be short, like Yes or No, so i have two questions at once.

**Question # 1** : i read theoretical explanations of IntPtr but it would be easier to understand it in comparison to native C++ pointers. Lets say i have some struct.

```
ref struct CData
{
    double Key;
};
```

With pointers in native code i can do :

```
1) int address = & CData; // if i need its address
2) double value = * CData; // if i need value of its field
3) void * pointer1 = CData; // if i want create pointer to struct
4) CData * pointer2 = CData; // if i want create pointer to struct
```

If CData is managed object then operations above can be done this way :

```
1) IntPtr address = GCHandle::Alloc(CData).AddrOfPinnedObject() // if i need address
2) cannot get one field within pointer, only direct access within CData.Key
3) IntPtr pointer = GCHandle::ToIntPtr(GCHandle::Alloc(CData)) // if i need pointer
4) the same as # 3
```

Am i right in my suggestions about similarities between pointers in native and managed code?

**Question # 2** : in my native app i do not have such type like **void ***, can i simply use **int** instead?

Full list of available data types presented here http://www.mql5.com/en/docs/basis/types  - which one can be a valid replacement for void * so i could use it in conjunction with IntPtr?

Comment: Every single line of your "I can do" code has a semantic error; most have two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that i found explanation that helped me to understand how i need to use that IntPtr.

- [Pinning an empty array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5478052/pinning-an-empty-array)
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2006/10/09/gchandle_5f00_intptr.aspx

**Following paragraph contains wrong suggestions.**

- I was asking about what IntPtr is because : i needed to move all my
  useful functions to C# library (DLL) and at the same time to be able
  to call them from unmanaged programs, like Metatrader. Unfortunately,
  Metatrader does not support pointers at all so i needed to figure out
  what exactly IntPtr returns me because if it is a common pointer then
  i cannot use it in MT. Also i thought that due to garbage collection
  cycles i cannot use interrior pointer so in any case i need to pin
  managed object and return exact address of the memory where it
  starts. I WAS WRONG.

**This is what i came to, already tested and it works so i believe it is correct implementation.**

- i should not think about pinned pointer because i was going to work
  with custom managed class which does not seem a Blittable Type and
  probably cannot be pinned. I could use some generic type, like byte
  array, pin it and get actual address with AddrOfPinnedObject. In this
  case i could manipulate with data from both managed and unmanaged
  programs but i decided to stay on the managed side only for the sake
  of simplicity.
- i realized that IntPtr is a pointer to a pointer to data, kind of void ** but for managed heap, which means that there are two pointers, the first one points to "handle" and "handle" points to real data. The second pointer ("handle") can change after GC cycle if actual data was relocated but the address of this handle stays the same which means that first pointer is persistent in any case. I was going to manipulate with data only from managed code so it was enough to save only first pointer and then, using this pointer, i always can obtain "handle", does not matter whether its value was changed by GC or not. Given handle - can get data itself.
- for me templates int_ptr<> and interrior_prt<> seem a black box so if i used them then probably it would be event harder to understand how exactly these handles work, maybe i will change my mind soon but for now i implemented it with GCHandle

**Example :**

Let's say i have class in C# DLL that i would like to use as a Shared Memory via Memory Mapped Files, i called it Connection :

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/138290/Programming-Memory-Mapped-Files-with-the-NET-Frame

Then in C++/CLI i have :

```
#define ECV extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void __cdecl

ECV MemoryOpen(char * name, int size, int &pointer)
{
    try
    {
        Connection ^ memory = gcnew Connection(); // instantiate managed class
        GCHandle gc = GCHandle::Alloc(memory); // get handle
        pointer = (int) GCHandle::ToIntPtr(gc); // get pointer to handle and pass it to unmanaged code by reference
        memory->Open(gcnew String(name), size); // do something from managed code
    }
    catch (Exception ^ e)
    {
        MessageBox::Show(e->Message + " " + e->StackTrace);
    }
}

ECV MemoryClose(int pointer)
{
    try
    {
        GCHandle gc = GCHandle::FromIntPtr(IntPtr(pointer)); // get pointer to handle
        Connection ^ memory = (Connection ^) gc.Target; // get data using handle
        memory->Close();
        gc.Free(); // free handle
    }
    catch (Exception ^ e)
    {
        MessageBox::Show(e->Message + " " + e->StackTrace);
    }
}
```

Comment: Any notes, corrections and recommendations to provided code are appreciated.

Comment: The main correction is that `IntPtr` isn't a pointer.  It's a pointer-sized storage.  It can hold a pointer to pinned data, and let you get the original pointer value back later.  Or hold a GCHandle to unpinned data.  Or store a pointer-sized OS handle (kernel handle = `HANDLE`, window handle = `HWND`, etc).  So it's wrong to say that "all `IntPtr` are `void**`" or anything like that.  The meaning of any particular `IntPtr` depends on what you stored in it.

Answer (score 6):

`IntPtr` is not a pointer.  It is an integer big enough to store a pointer, just like `uintptr_t` in standard C and C++.

In C++/CLI, the "pointer to managed object" type is the `interior_ptr<T>` and `pin_ptr<T>` pseudo-template.  Like a c# fixed block, `pin_ptr<T>` pins the object on the managed heap, allowing you to pass the pointer as a normal native pointer to existing code, without having the object move out from under that code.

There's very rarely any reason to use `GCHandle` directly in C++/CLI.  Use the `pin_ptr<T>` and `gcroot<T>` templates instead.  And there's good reason to avoid it, you made two serious mistakes in just one line of code in your question:

> ```
> GCHandle::Alloc(CData).AddrOfPinnedObject()
> ```

You leaked the GCHandle.  And you called `AddrOfPinnedObject` on a non-pinning GCHandle.

Use the C++/CLI tools built for this purpose.  They'll steer you away from such mistakes.

Comment: As about not pinned GCHandle - i omitted it in this particular example, i know that the second parameter allows me to choose what kind of handle to use Normal, Weak, Pinned etc.

Comment: As about leaked GCHandle - is this because it was not saved in local variable? Or where exactly this leak happened?

Comment: The main reason why i asked this question again is because i need to keep this handle in unmanaged code and maybe even somehow change object from there. In this case i need to understand what exactly was saved in this IntPtr. According to the first sentence in your answer this is a variable that stores pointer to a pointer to data, kind of CData ** and when i am doing IntPtr(...).ToPointer() i will get exact pointer to data, something like CData * or void *, right?

Comment: When i call AddrOfPinnedObject() i presume it should return me exact address in memory where my CData starts so i could access it from unmanaged code or it will return me address of a pointer to CData? Is there a chance to see some graphical representation of what IntPtr is?

Comment: @Art: You are quite confused, and I have no idea why you persist in trying to figure out *how* to use `IntPtr` without first worrying about *when* to use it.  Which is almost never.  Use `pin_ptr` instead.  `pin_ptr` takes care of pinning and unpinning, and can point to fields inside of an object.